# Is it possible to consolidate this into one query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am updating 2 columns and multiple rows. Currently I am running two different queries to get this done. Is it possible to have it done in one query?

```
UPDATE `messages` SET `from_delete` = NOW() WHERE `thread_hash` = 'abc' AND `from_user_id` = '6'

UPDATE `messages` SET `to_delete` = NOW() WHERE `thread_hash` = 'abc' AND `to_user_id` = '6'
```

Comment: And what is `it` ? Any code you can share to tell us about `it` ?

Comment: Start by describing the query conditions in plain English and you will find it pretty hard....

Comment: It almost seems like two queries is the appropriate solution to this\

Comment: Oops sorry, forgot to add the queries. Should be fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible, but it's tricky:

```
UPDATE `messages`
   SET `from_delete` = IF(`from_user_id` = '6',NOW(),`from_delete`)
     , `to_delete`   = IF(`to_user_id`   = '6',NOW(),`to_delete`  ) 
 WHERE (`thread_hash` = 'abc' AND `from_user_id` = '6')
    OR (`thread_hash` = 'abc' AND `to_user_id`   = '6')
```

The "trick" is to use a conditional in the assignment. If the row should not be updated, then assign the current value of the column to the column for a "no change" operation.

For completeness, you may want to add the condition on thread_hash to the conditional. although this doesn't change anything with the query:

```
UPDATE `messages`
   SET `from_delete` = IF(`thread_hash` = 'abc' AND `from_user_id` = '6'
                       ,NOW(),`from_delete`)
     , `to_delete`   = IF(`thread_hash` = 'abc' AND `to_user_id`   = '6'
                       ,NOW(),`to_delete`  ) 
 WHERE (`thread_hash` = 'abc' AND `from_user_id` = '6')
    OR (`thread_hash` = 'abc' AND `to_user_id`   = '6')
```

Comment: @TGH: It answers the question, is it possible to perform this in a single statement. I've used this technique, primarily to improve performance and scalability. Fewer SQL statements means fewer roundtrips to the database. We just need to make sure that the access plan isn't "worse" than the access plans of the two individual statements.

Comment: I don't disagree that it solves the problem. However, I am wondering if the approach has the side effect of being difficult to maintain if more complexity is added to the where clause.